# Ruby: Is using `srand` in initializer thread safe?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Is the follow code thread safe? I am worried srand may be a variable that is not thread safe. I have a rails app and going to be using Puma with 5-10 threads. I do not want to cause issues.

```
class Test
  def initialize(seed)
    srand seed          # => 1, 222, 222, 111
  end                   # => :initialize

  def letter
    %w[a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z aa bb cc dd].sample  # => "g", "u"
  end                                                                           # => :letter
  
  def letter1
    %w[a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z aa bb cc dd].sample  # => "g", "u"
  end                                                                           # => :letter1
end                                                                             # => :letter1

Test.new(222).letter   # => "g"
Test.new(222).letter1  # => "g"

Test.new(111).letter   # => "u"
Test.new(111).letter1  # => "u"
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by "thread-safe". The program will still work, Ruby won't enter in an inconsistent state and no data will be lost. However, the default random number generator is global, shared between threads; it will be up to thread timing to see which thread receives which random number. If your intention is that all threads just get random numbers from a single RNG, your code is fine - though the results might not be repeatable, which probably defeats the purpose of `srand`.

If you want to make sure that each `Test` only generates numbers independently (and repeatably), you want to have each `Test` have its own random number generator:

```
class Test
  def initialize(seed)
    @random = Random.new(seed)
  end

  def letter
    %w[a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z aa bb cc dd].sample(random: @random)
  end
end

t1 = Test.new(111)
t2 = Test.new(222)
3.times.map { t1.letter }
# => ["u", "m", "u"]
3.times.map { t2.letter }
# => ["u", "m", "u"]
```